# How to use params in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla and i want to develop a module in which i want to use params value from menu item into my module.so i want know how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried researching anything, or have you tried anything of your own?

Comment: Start with this http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    //lets take article param for example

    $articleId = JRequest::getInt('id');
    $params = new JParameter( $articleId );

    //supose you want fetch image

    $image  = $params->get( 'image' );
    ?>
```

For more information go to this [link](http://api.joomla.org/11.4/Joomla-Platform/Parameter/JParameter.html)